# looking for http sandbox

Tags: http, testing

I am looking for publicly accessible web server that I can test my AJAX requests on. I remember there were a site that would show me all my requests, etc, but I forget the name. Can anyone recommend something?

EDIT:

I have a web server on localhost, and I want to send a POST to another server from my Javascript. This is to test my cross origin functionality. I know I can set up my own web server and change my local DNS settings so that it appears as another domain, but I would rather use an existing server than writing my own server side code.

Comment: Had the same issue, I was trying to remember https://hookbin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this, I suppose. Check their [API documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) for guides and a few [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/NF2jz/light/).

Comment: thanks. I have updated my question. This is not I think what I am looking for.

Comment: But it doesn't have to be called from within jsFiddle! I mean, you may try just to (if you want to check cross-domain) send POST request to http://jsfiddle.net/echo/json/, for example, with 'json' param encapsulating some data to test... or you need something else?

Comment: thanks. I also found http://requestb.in/. none of them would allow me to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the response though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send and fetch data from a different domain, without changing the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). This completely avoids the whole cross origin pain but you'll have to use a GET request though.

You can test this with the jsfiddle url:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/
```

eg:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/?name=fred&callback=callbackName
```

will return

```
callbackName({"name": "fred"});
```